# Regular expression with counting

Tags: regex

I have strings of 0s and 1s.
I want a regular expression such that the number of 0s is less than the number of 1s.

Example:

```
0111 - match (there is 1x0 and 3x1 and 1 < 3)
00011 - pattern fails (3x0 and 2x1 but 3<2 is false)
0101010 - pattern fails (4x0 and 3x1 but 4<3 is false)
```

Comment: Please specify regex flavor.

Comment: `I have` .......`I want`.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pcre and probably Perl, you can do it using a recursive pattern:

```
^((?:0(?1)??1|1(?1)??0)*+)(?:1(?1))+$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/alpwgU/3)

details:

```
^
( # group 1: matches balanced 0 and 1 
    (?:
        0(?1)??1 # part that starts with 0 and ends with 1
                # (?1) calls the group 1 subpattern itself (recursion) 
      |
        1(?1)??0 # same thing for 1 ... 0
    )*+ # repeat
)
(?:
    1    
    (?1)
)+ # ensure there's at least one 1 that isn't matched by (?1)
$
```

---

With .net regex engine:

```
^(?>(?<c>0)|(?<-c>1))*(?(c)(?!$))(?:1(?>(?<c>0)|(?<-c>1))*(?(c)(?!$)))+$
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3E%28%3F%3Cc%3E0%29%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E1%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%24%29%29%28%3F%3A1%28%3F%3E%28%3F%3Cc%3E0%29%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E1%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%24%29%29%29%2B%24&i=100001111&o=m)

It is more intuitive this time:

`(?<c>...)` increases a counter c and `(?<-c>...)` decreases the same counter. The conditional `(?(c)(?!$))` fails when the counter c isn't zero *(`(?!$)` is an always failing subpattern)*.

The global structure of this pattern is the same than the previous:

```
^ (balanced parts)* (?: 1 (balanced parts)* )+ $
```

---

An other possible structure with pcre is:

```
^ (?: balanced parts | (1) )*+ (force to fail if capture group doesn't exist) $
```

pcre:

```
^(?:((?:0(?1)?1|1(?1)?0)+)|(1))*+(?(2)|(*F))$
```

Comment: As I remember this problem was designated as an exercise part in Peter Linz's *An introduction to Formal Languages and Automata* book. However I should ask how did you come with this idea to put `1(?1)` as a compulsory expression and not within an alternation in the first capturing group?

Comment: @revo: `(?:1(?1))+` is only the improved form (unrolled form) of `1 (?:1|(?1))*`. You can also write it this way: https://regex101.com/r/zE1Nqt/1

Comment: 1) As I think of this language this way `S -> SS|0S1|1S0|1S|1` I can't understand how you made `1(?1)` mandatory yet. Why is it mandatory? (I should say grammar's production doesn't produce e.g. `w=10110` so I'd appreciate if you lighten things up) 2) What should we do to avoid CB on strings having sloppy zeros: [**`111111111110000000000011101011010001111111`**](https://regex101.com/r/alpwgU/2)?

Comment: @revo: 1) `1(?1)` is not mandatory since it is enclosed in a group with the `+` quantifier: `(?:1(?1))+`. 2) Using recursion always implies a limitation (as any code) and this kind of pattern (the recursive one) may quickly stop to work when the subject is too long, too "complicated" or needs a too deep level of recursion. I haven't the time yet, but I will try something tonight to improve it (without any certainty).

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it called mandatory when it should match at least one time?

Comment: @revo: Sorry, I made a contradiction, yes, `1(?1)` is mandatory since the OP wants more 1s than 0s.

Comment: So back to the first question, why is it mandatory and not along with an alternation in the first capturing group ? (please consider my thoughts on grammar)

Comment: @revo: I'm not familiar with grammar notations, but if you write something like `^((?:0(?1)?1|1(?1)?0|1)+)$` this doesn't guarantee that the branch with the 1 will match at least 1 time.

Comment: Would you elaborate on this part *this doesn't guarantee*? If engine does backtrack then does not it mean `1` is always considered to be matched to put an end to a matching process?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are used to match patterns, but you seem to want to count instances of characters. This is not something which regular expressions, to my knowledge do.

What you would need to do would be to create an array or some other structure to hold the counter values for the specific characters you are after. You would then iterate over the input string and depending on the character at hand, you update the appropriate counter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve your goals without regex.

FOREACH:

```
string s = "10101010011";
int zeros = 0;
int ones = 0;
foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (c == '0')
    {
        zeros++;
    }
    else
    {
        ones++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(zeros < ones);
Console.ReadLine();
```

LINQ:

```
string s = "10101010011";
int zeros = s.Count(x => x == '0');
int ones = s.Count(x => x == '1');
Console.WriteLine(zeros < ones);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify the language. This is how you can achieve it in Python without using regex. You can port this logic to your language.

```
a= """0111
00011
0101010"""

a = a.split('\n')
print a

for b in a:
    zeroes = list(b).count('0')
    ones = list(b).count('1')
    if zeroes < ones:
        print b
```

Output:

```
['0111', '00011', '0101010']
0111
```