# Why this regex clear javascript file

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have this code:

```
$tags = implode("|", array("a", "script", "link", "iframe", "img", "object"));
$attrs = implode("|", array("href", "src", "data"));
$any_tag = "\w+(?:\s*=\s*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])?";
$replace = array(
    "/(<(?:$tags)(?:\s*$any_tag)*\s*(?:$attrs)=[\"'])(?![\"']?(?:data:|#))([^'\"]+)([\"'][^>]*>)/" => function($match) {
        return $match[1] . $match[2] . $match[3]; // return same data
    }
);
$page = preg_replace_callback_array($replace, $page);
echo $page;
```

and I'm runing this code against https://duckduckgo.com/d2038.js and $page is empty after executing replace, why? If I've added `print_r($match)`; in callback I've got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href='/a'>
    [1] => <a href='
    [2] => /a
    [3] => '>
)
```

the same happen if I assign the value of replace to another variable. Why the page is empty?

If I runing this in regex101 it match more elements https://regex101.com/r/CPGuKd/1 and it don't clear the output.

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use the appropriate extensions instead (DOM, SimpleXML, XMLReader, etc.)

Comment: [HTML can't be safely parsed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov how I'm suppose to parse html inside javascript?

Comment: For convenience, actual regex executed: /(<(?:a|script|link|iframe|img|object)(?:\s*\w+(?:\s*=\s*[\"'][^\"']*[\"'])?)*\s*(?:href|src|data)=[\"'])(?![\"']?(?:data:|#))([^'\"]+)([\"'][^>]*>)/

Comment: @DainisAbols WTF, that is the weirdest SO answer I have ever seen... :)

Comment: @revo $self is url with __proxy_url= param and proxy_url encode url in base64 and prepend base64:, same happen if I just put  `return $match[1] . $match[2] . $match[3];` in callback.

Comment: Does `$page` hold nothing or `NULL` (`var_dump($page)`)?

Comment: @revo the result is NULL.

Comment: @revo I've got PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR. Any clues why I got this error.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: unfortunately you can't use XMLReader for html (to be precise, you can only use it with a perfectly XML compliant xhtml document).

Comment: Hey @CasimiretHippolyte, STBU, but I like to bring your attention to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320032/regular-expression-with-counting).

Comment: @revo: interesting, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final cooked regex from within your code is this:

```
(<(?:a|script|link|iframe|img|object)(?:\s*\w+(?:\s*=\s*["'][^"']*["'])?)*\s*(?:href|src|data)=["'])(?!["']?(?:data:|#))([^'"]+)(["'][^>]*>)
```

which is different from your live demo and causes a [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/CPGuKd/2).

According to your live demo there should be a little change in PHP code:

```
"/(<(?:$tags)(?:\s*$$any_tag)*...
                   ^
```

Comment: Since on iterating over input string regex engine would fail sooner if it has to while using a `$` (end of input string / line). Yes, it doesn't make sense without analyzing regex itself so I'd go with a possessive quantifier `\s++`. Now makes sense.

Comment: I've tested again and it don't work, it don't match `<link rel="stylsheet" href="url"/>`